# Why is Form '#states' not working?

Tags: javascript

I've used the [Address Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield) module in my registration form with other fields. I've one select field to display some numbers and one textfield to get some numbers from users. This textfield should be required based on select field value. So I've handled this using '#states' in hook_form_alter. This is my code:

```
function arep_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "user_register_form") {
    //field licence number is required only if profession is nurse
    $form['field_license_number']['#states'] = array(
      'required' => array(
        ':input[name="field_profession[' . LANGUAGE_NONE . ']"]' => array(
          array('value' => t('8')),
          array('value' => t('9')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It is working fine, but I have another issue with the Address Field module. After changing country in address field, when I try to change select field value, '*' is added more than once.

I've tried to get `$form_state['values']` after changing country in address field but it displays only empty values. So I can't make it work as I expected.

How to solve this issue?